# Reformulate Traveling Salesman Problem in areas traversed problem

Tags: graph-theory, traveling-salesman-problem

I was wondering whether one has ever considered to reformulate TSP in terms of the areas traversed in either direction. Thus take three initial points of the solution they span a triangle with a certain area and so do the next three points, etc. My assumption is that the total area traversed this way is minimal for our TSP solution over all possible (infinite and looping) routes.

Main idea I have is to reformulate the TSP into an area minimisation problem on a network s.t. instead of a set of edges we retain again a network with medial axis the TSP solution

Looking forward,

Alfons.

Given previous remarks I think I have to reformulate my inquiry.

Perhaps it is better to start off with creating a full connected network of all (possibly degenerate) triangles from given n points in 2 dimensional Euclidean space. One can imagine all the points on a circle. In addition,  each triple of points forming a triangle having a certain Hernon area. The network of points has associated a network of triangles with a total area being the sum of the Hernon areas of the triangles. Of course, this total area is much larger than that is needed for the sequence of triangles along a TSP solution with a fixed starting- and equal end-point and with p1, p2 and p3 being consecutive points on the solution (network triangle points are not necessarily coinciding with such triples p1, p2 and p3).

Now I was wondering whether one has consider defining some kind of geometric flow on the full network of triangles with one special focus point (starting-end-point) such that one retains  in the limit as solution that is the same as a corresponding TSP solution?

There is a n-body approach that looks interesting
"https://www.pearson.com/content/dam/one-dot-com/one-dot-com/us/en/files/Proceedings-ICTCM2019-BryantWyatt.pdf"
but Lennard-Jones potential seems to me a bit arbitrary.

Might another metric potential defined by the n-points all together instead of 2 or 3 points perhaps more appropriate for defining such geometric flow that ensures collapse of the full network on a circle with one focus point and the other points ordered according to the TSP solution?

In reply to the latest suggestions/comments:

Assume we have n-points x_i in Euclidean space and define a scalar function on this space f: x -> (1/(1 + |x-x_1|^2)) * ... * (1/(1+ |x-x_n|^2)) and consider its isophotes and flowlines landscape.

Why this function? main reason is that on the one hand the locations of the n-points coincide simply with the maxima of this function; of course there are minima but of course they relate to the other aspects of the n-points. On the other hand, this way the geometric n-point Euclidean structure in my view is still fully covered in the isophote-flowline landscape.

Conjecture: (A-)Symmetric traveling salesman problem is equivalent to following  the deep scale-space structure of the mergers of the singularities (manifolds) (maxima/minima) of the euclidean (affine or other) geometric flow defined by dx/dt =  grad (f) (t is the scale parameter).

Naturally, closest points  and clusters will merge at higher scales. The order in which groups of points cluster is clear but even for 3 points it is not yet clear whether x_3 connects x_1 or x_2. However, the order of x_3 collapsing on x_1 and x_3 collapsing on x2 is normally known considering the deep scale-space structure of the singularity manifolds, allowing to cut one of them out. Iteratively, applying this deep structure analysis method the solution to the TSP pops up.

Comment: Have you tried this for the 4 points making up the corners of a square? Does your area criterion distinguish the optimal path from one including connections along the diagonal of the square?

Comment: What exactly are you proposing to minimize? Area(p_1,p_2,p_3) + Area(p_2,p_3,p_4) + ... + Area(x_n,x_1,x_2), or something else? (I'm not sure what you mean by "the next three points".)

Comment: What is a "Hernon area'?  Does it mean the same as "area"?

Comment: @DanielAsimov maybe a reference to Heron's formula, which relates the area of a triangle to its side lengths?

Comment: @ahsalden I agree with Michael Engelhardt that you should check if your conjecture holds for simple cases, and probably give some reasoning for why you expect it to be true in general. Bear in mind that in general, the weights involved in the Travelling Salesman Problem do not have to correspond to physical distances.

Comment: If it has to be a conjecture: